# Laravel different validation rule if another field exists

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I pass work and mobile phones to my form. I want to make sure that they are different. My validation rules are:

```
'form_data.mobile_phone' => 'max:255|different:form_data.work_phone',
'form_data.work_phone' => 'max:255',
```

However, when I pass only mobile phone I got validation error that mobile phone should be different from work phone. I tried to put `sometimes` rule with the same effect.

How to check that mobile phone and work phone are different only if both are present?

Comment: I've tried with your exact validation rules. And in my case it works like a charm. Even for single value in any of the fields.

Answer (score -1):

Put a PHP Check before validations eg.assuming you have $data variable containing all posted data then do something like

```
if(isset($data['work_phone']) && isset($data['mobile_phone']))
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: This is not not the right way to do this check in Laravel. There is already a solution for that in the framework.

Here it is

***Determining If An Input Value Is Present***

To determine if a value is present on the request, you may use the `has` method. The `has` method returns `true` if the value is present **and** is not an empty string:


`if ($request->has('name')) {
    // do something
}`
[Reference Doccumentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input)